# How to convert a text file to a dataframe (dictionaries first)?

Tags: python, string, dictionary, dataframe, text

I know this may not possible but I still want to ask this questions:

My text file looks like below: four questions with answers.
[image]

Is there any change transferring the text file to a dataframe? (questions as columns and answers for rows)
This is the expected output
[image]

```
txtfile=StringIO("""1. How do you like this product?
I really don't like this product. It broke after 3-month use
2. Rate your purchasing experience from one to ten?  Will you refer the 
product to your friend?
from 1 to 10, I gave 2
3. What part do you like the most for this product?
The outlook of the product was good but the quality was low
4. Do you have any recommendations that can help us improve?
I don’t think so""")
```

Above are the text

Comment: Why do you need a DataFrame for this? Are you only recording one person's answer for each question?

Comment: @duncster94 I need to import the tabular file (csv) to the database finally.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're asking, could you clarify your answer above by including an example of the output you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
from io import StringIO
txtfile=StringIO("""1. How do you like this product?
Answer1
2. Rate your purchasing experience from one to ten?  Will you refer the product to your friend?
Answer2
3. What part do you like the most for this product?
Answer3
4. Do you have any recommendations that can help us improve?
Answer4""")

df = pd.read_csv(txtfile,header=None)

df['Answers'] = df[0].str.extract('Answer(\d)')

df = df.bfill()
df = df[~df[0].str.startswith('Answer')]
df.set_index(0).T
```

Update:

```
from io import StringIO
txtfile=StringIO("""1. How do you like this product?
Answer1
2. Rate your purchasing experience from one to ten?  Will you refer the product to your friend?
Answer2
3. What part do you like the most for this product?
Answer3
4. Do you have any recommendations that can help us improve?
Answer4""")

df = pd.read_csv(txtfile,header=None)

ans_dict={'Answer1':"I don't like this product", 'Answer2':'from 1 to 10, I gave 2', 'Answer3':'The outlook of the product was good but quality was low', 'Answer4':"I don't think so Hope it helps"}


df['Answers'] = df[df[0].str.startswith('Answer')]

df['Answers'] = df['Answers'].map(ans_dict)

df = df.bfill()
df = df[~df[0].str.startswith('Answer')]
df.set_index(0).T
```

Comment: Hi Scott, thank you so much for your answer and it helps. But what if the four answers are real text, for example, "I don't like this product" for Answer 1, and "The purchasing exp was awesome"...? The Answer1, Answer2 are examples...Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Can you add an image or code that would be your expected out
put from this data?

Comment: I updated the question just now. Thanks for your help again.

Comment: Hi Scott Any thoughts? Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, you need to supply me the translation of what answer =1 and what answer 2 equals for each question.

Comment: Answer1=I really don't like this product. It broke after 3-month use
Answer2=from 1 to 10, I gave 2
Answer3=The outlook of the product was good but the quality was low
Answer4=I don’t think so

Comment: The name "Answer1", "Answer2", Answer3, Answer4 are made-up. They are the real comments...

Comment: Thank you for the help! Is it possible not creating the dictionary "ans_dict"?

Comment: Then where do I get the mapping of Answer1 to the text "I really don't like this product."?